# Cellular Emulator :com4 is in use, please close Device emulator if it is running and then retry

Tags: c#

### [link text](http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/3381/errorb.png)

I installed windows mobile 6.0 standard sdk but later found out my program needs professional versions.

No matter how i uninstall the old sdk from control panels>add/remove or trying to install the Professional version over it, this happens. Now i couldn't even run a smart device project/solution from Visual studio 2008.

Now i can't work on my project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer to this question is to reformat your computer. Care centers have told me to do that every time I explained a problem to them.

Answer (score 2):

I have Windows XP SP3 Eng with some additional updates.
For me works to delete registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\xpvcom by registry editor (Run => regedit). After deletition it works with out restart.
to.kykygle.me.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same problem. The following helped me.

Goto Control Panel-> System Properties ->Hardware ->Device Manager

Under the System Devices -> Remove XPVCOM.

Try uninstalling now. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add what worked for me:

(From http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=12061641&postcount=7, who got it from http://faqs.edujini-labs.com/55_12_en.html)

Like one of the other answers here, the trick is to uninstall XPVCOM, but the additional thing to do is *reinstall* XPVCOM. My guess is that if there's a problem with the installation of that, it breaks the other uninstall.

1. Go to your device manager. My Computer -> Properties -> Hardware -> Device Manager
2. Go to the entry of "System Devices"
3. Towards the end, you will find an entry "XPVCOM" (XP Virtual COM Port, I guess). Uninstall it. You will see this entry only when you get the error "COM in use, please verify".
4. Now, go to the folder where you have the Cellular Emulator. The default location is "C:\Program Files\Windows SDK 6 Professional\Tools\Cellular Emulator".
5. You will find a utility InstallXPVCom.exe. At the command prompt, execute the following:

   InstallXPVcom.exe Install
6. Try uninstalling again, it will work.